# Pandas Dataframe group by, column with a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im using jupyter notebooks, my current dataframe looks like the following:

```
players_mentioned  |  tweet_text    |  polarity
______________________________________________
[Mane, Salah]      |  xyz           |    0.12
[Salah]            |  asd           |    0.06
```

How can I group all players individually and average their polarity?

Currently I have tried to use:

```
df.groupby(df['players_mentioned'].map(tuple))['polarity'].mean()
```

But this will return a dataframe grouping all the mentions when together as well as separate, how best can I go about splitting the players up and then grouping them back together.

An expected output would contain

```
 player  | polarity_average
____________________________
  Mane   |   0.12
  Salah  |   0.09
```

In other words how to group by each item in the lists in every row.

Comment: Your attempted code is not even a close approximation of what you're trying to do. Can you explain what you mean by "splitting them up"? It would be helpful to see your expected output.

Comment: Added an expected output @coldspeed . I understand my attempt is wrong that is why I need some guidance

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.

Comment: Can you please run `result.loc[result['players_mentioned'].str.contains('Alderweireld'), 'players_mentioned'].tolist()` on the resultant df from my code, and tell me what the output is?

Comment: I see the issue, there is a space at the start of the name, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`unnesting` idiom from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/4909087).

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

You can now call `groupby` on the unnested "players_mentioned" column.

```
(unnesting(df, ['players_mentioned'])
    .groupby('players_mentioned', as_index=False).mean())

  players_mentioned  polarity
0              Mane      0.12
1             Salah      0.09
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to group by players_mentioned and get the averatge for that players popularity score this should do it.

```
df.groupby('players_mentioned').polarity.agg('mean')
```

Comment: This does not produce OP's expected output.